# After transformation by Byte Buddy, how to get class information without loading or saving class?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

For an existing private method, such as a `package private` default constructor of a class `ContentItem`, I used below code to set the method to be protected.

By testing code below and Byte Buddy's test case `AbstractDynamicTypeBuilderForInliningTest.java::testMethodTransformationExistingMethod()`, I found that if I load `dynamicType` or save it into file, the default constructor of loaded class and the saved class did become `protected`, but the constructor in `dynamicType.getTypeDescription().getDeclaredMethods()` still keeps original modifier, i.g. 0 (package private).

So the question is, how can I get the transformed class info without loading or saving it? I need to use the transformed class info to add default constructor into the sub classes of class `ContentItem` (the sub classes' default constructor need to call `ContentItem` 's default constructor).

```
public class ContentItem {
    ContentItem() {}

    private ContentItem(UIDBasedID uid, String archetypeNodeId, DvText name, Archetyped archetypeDetails, FeederAudit feederAudit, Set<Link> links, Pathable parent) {
        ......;
    }

Class<?> clazz = ContentItem.class;
DynamicType.Unloaded<?> dynamicType = ByteBuddy().redefine(clazz)
    .constructor(takesArguments((List<TypeDescription>) (List) Collections.EMPTY_LIST))
    .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredConstructor()))
    .transform(MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PROTECTED))
    .make();
TypeDescription typeDescription = dynamicType.getTypeDescription();
dynamicType.saveIn(...);
Class<?> tmpType = dynamicType.load(...).getLoaded();
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided type description does not include any overridden methods of super classes or transformed methods for performance reasons.

You need to reparse the byte array if you want to read the fully transformed type. Simply provide the byte array to a type pool that interprets the bytes.

Comment: Yeah, it works well using `TypeDescription typeDescription = TypePool.Default.of(new ClassFileLocator.ForFolder(new File(destClassFilePath))).describe(clazz.getName()).resolve();`.    

A further question, I want to just change modifier of existing default constructor without changing method body, how do I change the `intercept(...)` in code `....intercept(MethodCall.invoke(clazz.getSuperclass().getDeclaredConstructor()))
    .transform(MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PROTECTED))` to achieve it?

Comment: Just provide a matcher isConstructor().and(takesArguments(0)) for the transformer and interceptor.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not describe my 'further question' clearly. Let's reiterate it. Suppose the original private default constructor has body like `{this.someArray = new ArrayList(...);}`. I want to change the modifier of the default constructor but keep using its original body. I wish I can execute `ByteBuddy().redefine(clazz).constructor(isDefaultConstructor()).transform(MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PROTECTED))`, but I can not because the interface returned by `constructor(...) ` has no method `transform(...)`. <To continue>

Comment: Then I have to insert call to `intercept(...)` between `constructor(...)` and `transform(...)`, the code become `...constructor(isDefaultConstructor()).intercept(...).transform(...)`. In `intercept(...)`, I want to keep using the original body of the default constructor. How to achieve it?